# Choose contact procedure not working on Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts, android-contacts

In my Android app, a button click triggers this function, which is used to let the user choose a phone number from his contact list.

```
private void addContact () {
    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    try {
        startActivityForResult (intent, 1);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { }
}
```

On almost all devices, it works perfectly, but it does not work on my Samsung Galaxy S4 mini (Android 4.4.4). There, the only thing that happens is that the `onActivityResult()` function of my activity is called with `resultCode` being equal to `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

Comment: That is likely to be a bug in that particular Samsung model, though getting rid of your `setType()` might help, as `ACTION_PICK` does not use a MIME type.

Comment: I removed `setType()`, but nothing changed.